# Compress image size to 1.5 MB while sending to multipart ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, multipartform-data

I am uploading image with size less than 1.5 MB ( Selecting in imagePickerController) after that I am saving it to Userdefault, but when I am trying to fetch it its size get increase. So at the time of uploading it to Multipart am again trying to compressing it as below. It's giving me "2122 Bytes". That's ok as its less than 1.5 MB. But main issue is I am unable to upload it.

```
let compressData = UIImage(data:UserDefaultValues.imagep1! as Data)!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0)

print("length:", UIImage(data:compressData!)!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0)!)//2122 bytes

let compressData2 = UIImage(data:UserDefaultValues.imagep3! as Data)?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0) 

print("length2:", UIImage(data:compressData2!)!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0)!)//2122 bytes


multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                    multipartFormData.append(compressData!, withName: "image", fileName: "", mimeType: "image/png")
                    multipartFormData.append("\(storyid)".data(using: .utf8)! , withName: "story_id")
                    multipartFormData.append(compressData2!, withName: "series_image", fileName: "", mimeType: "image/png")
                    multipartFormData.append("\(seriesid)".data(using: .utf8)! , withName: "series_id")

},
```

Comment: you want to resize image data ..??

Comment: Yes to 1.5 MB n less....I am getting 2122 bytes but still I am getting that Image size should not be more than 1.5 MB :(

Comment: @RanuDhurandhar Have you used " UIImageJPEGRepresentation " function for UIImage ? OR you have to change your  compressionQuality: 0 to compressionQuality: 0.5

Comment: I want to compress the size for 1.5 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
func sendStorySeriesImage(seriesid: Int, storyid: Int){
    let sv = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: view)
    guard let compressData2 = (UIImage(data:UserDefaultValues.imagep1! as Data)!).jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else {
        return
    }
    guard let compressData = (UIImage(data:UserDefaultValues.imagep1! as Data)!).jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else {
        return
    }

let url = URL(string: Constants.wevlrBaseUrl + Constants.privateLink + Constants.createstoryseriesImage)!

Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

    multipartFormData.append("\(storyid)".data(using: .utf8)! , withName: "story_id")
    multipartFormData.append("\(seriesid)".data(using: .utf8)! , withName: "series_id")
    multipartFormData.append(compressData, withName: "image", fileName: "\(UUID().uuidString).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
    multipartFormData.append(compressData2, withName: "series_image", fileName: "\(UUID().uuidString).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")

},
        to: url,
        method : .post,
        headers : Constants.headers,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

        upload.responseJSON { response in

            debugPrint(response)
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: sv)
                let dict = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode

                if(statusCode == 201) {
                            UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: sv)
                            self.alert(title: "Success!", message: (dict["msg"] as? String)!)



               }else{
                            UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: sv)
                            self.alert(title: "Alert!", message: (dict["msg"] as? String)!)
                           }
            break
            case .failure(_):
             self.alert(title: "Alert!", message: "Something went wrong. Please try again.")
            break
            }

        }
        case .failure(_):
         self.alert(title: "Alert!", message: "Something went wrong. Please try again.")
        break
        }
    }
        )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Image Compression extension](https://gist.github.com/sureshmopidevi/20c6b03b6c23a2e768b62a826a6a0035) might help you to maintain sendable image size consistant.

> Uploading multipartFormData

```swift
 Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFromData in
                    if !fileData.isEmpty {
                        multipartFromData.append(fileData, withName: "file", fileName: "\(UUID().uuidString).png", mimeType: "image/png")
                    }

                }, to:URL , method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { result in
                    print(result)

                    switch result {
                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 300).responseString(completionHandler: { _ in
                         print("Upload success")
                        })
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some step for uploading image on server with sample code

Step1: Upload Image with URLSession

```
    var croppedImage = UIImage()

    func imageUploadRequest(){
    let getUserData :UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let User_Id = getUserData.value(forKey: "userid")
    print("userid :\(String(describing: User_Id))!)")
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "Enter API String Here");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let param = [
        "user_id"  : "\(User_Id!)",

    ]
    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    //Pass image in compressImage function
    let compressedImage = self.compressImage(image: croppedImage)
    //Convert It NSData To UIImage and also pass scale value for compression
    convertedImage = UIImage(data:compressedImage as Data,scale:1.0)!
    print("print Lates compress image size : \(convertedImage.size)")
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(convertedImage, 1)
    if(imageData==nil)  { return; }
    request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param, filePathKey: "fileToUpload", imageDataKey: imageData! as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data
    //Pass This converted Image To Server
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        // You can print out response object
        print("******* response = \(String(describing: response))")
        // Print out reponse body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")
        //Show Alert after successfull uploaded
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //resolved view is not hiararchy issue.
            let createProfileVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CreateProfileViewController") as! CreateProfileViewController
            let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = createProfileVC
        }
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
            print(json)
            self.imageView.image = nil;
        }catch
        {
            print(error)
        }
      }
    task.resume()
  }

func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData();
    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }
    let filename = "profileImage"
    let mimetype = "image/jpg"
    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.append(imageDataKey as Data)
    body.appendString(string: "\r\n")

    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body
}

func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
}
```

Step2: Image compression

```
 //Need to convert NSData to UIImage
func compressImage(image:UIImage) -> NSData {
    // Reducing file size to a 10th

    var actualHeight : CGFloat = image.size.height
    var actualWidth : CGFloat = image.size.width
    var maxHeight : CGFloat = 1136.0
    var maxWidth : CGFloat = 640.0
    var imgRatio : CGFloat = actualWidth/actualHeight
    var maxRatio : CGFloat = maxWidth/maxHeight
    var compressionQuality : CGFloat = 0.5

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth){
        if(imgRatio < maxRatio){
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
        }
        else if(imgRatio > maxRatio){
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
        }
        else{
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
            compressionQuality = 1;
        }
    }


    var rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y:0.0 , width:actualWidth , height: actualHeight)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    image.draw(in: rect)
    var img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!, compressionQuality);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageData as! NSData;
}
```

}

extension NSMutableData {

```
func appendString(string: String) {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
    append(data!)
}
```

}

Comment: i will try this

Comment: You can manage desire compression size by using compressionQuality parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress the image before send the image in multipart. With below function you will get compressed image data and image with minimum loss of quality in completion.

```
extension UIImage {
func compressImageBelow(kb: Double, completion:(UIImage?, Data?) -> Void) {
    if let imageData = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
    {
      var resizingImage = self
      var imageSizeKB = Double(imageData.count) / 1000.0
      var imgFinalData: Data = imageData
      while imageSizeKB > kb {
            if let resizedImage = resizingImage.resized(withPercentage: 0.9),
                let imageData = resizedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
                resizingImage = resizedImage
                imageSizeKB = Double(imageData.count) / 1000.0 // ! Or devide for 1024 if you need KB but not kB
                imgFinalData = imageData
                print("There were \(imageData.count) bytes")
                let bcf = ByteCountFormatter()
                bcf.allowedUnits = [.useMB] // optional: restricts the units to MB only
                bcf.countStyle = .file
                let string = bcf.string(fromByteCount: Int64(imageData.count))
                print("formatted result: \(string)")
            }
        }
        completion(self, imgFinalData);
    }
    completion(nil, nil);
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
image.compressImageBelow(kb: 1500.0, completion: { (compressedImage, imageData) in
  guard let imgData = imageData else {
    return
  }
  //Use compressedImage here or
  //Send img data in multiparts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me

```
func resize(_ expectedSizeInMb:Int) -> Data? {
        guard let fileSize = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else {return nil}
        let Size = CGFloat(Double(fileSize.count)/1024/1024)
        // I am checking 5 MB size here you check as you want
        if Size > CGFloat(expectedSizeInMb) {
            let sizeInBytes: CGFloat = CGFloat(expectedSizeInMb * 1024 * 1024)
            let leastExpectedSize: CGFloat = (CGFloat(expectedSizeInMb) - 1) * 1024 * 1024
            var imgData:Data?
            var start: CGFloat = 0
            var end: CGFloat = 1
            var mid: CGFloat = (end+start)/2
            while true {
                imgData = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: CGFloat(mid))
                print("current image size \(CGFloat(imgData!.count)/(1024*1024))")
                print("1st \(start) 2nd \(mid) 3rd \(end)")
                if CGFloat(imgData?.count ?? 0) > sizeInBytes {
                    end = mid
                    mid = (start+end)/2
                } else if CGFloat(imgData?.count ?? 0) < sizeInBytes && CGFloat(imgData?.count ?? 0) < leastExpectedSize {
                    start = mid
                    mid = (start+end)/2
                } else {
                    print("returning")
                    return imgData
                }
            }
        }
        return fileSize
    }
```